# autohotkey: how to resize window by both absolute and relative height after `InputBox`

Tags: windows, window, autohotkey

I use

```
InputBox, height_i, Resize, Height:, , 140, 130
```

to get input, then use `height_i` to change window size accordingly.

The question is how to differ below cases:

- `+80` is given, use current height + 80 as new height.
- `80` is given, use 80 as new height.
- `-80` is given, use current height - 80 as new height.

get current height by `WinGetActiveStats`, set window size with `WinMove`.

I currently use

```
WinMove, ahk_id %window%, , , , , height_i
```

which could only set window height via absolute height. How could I set window height by relative height too, eg `+80`, `-80`.

The original idea comes from [Program to resize any window to specific sizes](https://superuser.com/a/429845/487198)

**EDIT EDIT**

Actually I use a more complex variant to set one of the four (X,Y,width,height) of active window. See my answer below.

**EDIT**

In the last, I use below

```
#=:: ; set height of active window, `A` for active window
    InputBox, height_i, Resize, Height:, , 140, 130
    first_char := SubStr(height_i, 1, 1)
    if (first_char = "+" or first_char = "-")
    {
        WinGetPos,,,,height, A
        height_i += height
    }
    WinMove, A, , , , , height_i
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

At last, I use below to change one of the four (X,Y,width,height) of active window.

```
#=:: ; set X/Y/width/height of window, `A` for active window
    InputBox, new_i, Resize, Height:, , 140, 130
    prefix := ""
    first_char := SubStr(new_i, 1, 1)
    if (first_char = "x" or first_char = "y" or first_char = "w" or first_char = "h") {
        prefix := first_char
        new_i := SubStr(new_i,2)
        first_char := SubStr(new_i, 1, 1)
    }
    if (first_char = "+" or first_char = "-")
    {
        if (prefix = "x")
            WinGetPos,old,,,, A
        else if (prefix = "y")
            WinGetPos,,old,,, A
        else if (prefix = "w")
            WinGetPos,,,old,, A
        else
            WinGetPos,,,,old, A
        new_i += old
    }
        if (prefix = "x")
            WinMove, A, , new_i, , ,
        else if (prefix = "y")
            WinMove, A, , , new_i, ,
        else if (prefix = "w")
            WinMove, A, , , , new_i,
        else
            WinMove, A, , , , , new_i
    return
```

**Example of usage**,
after <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, type below in the inputbox

- `800`, set height to 800
- `+300`, increase height by 300
- `h+300`, increase height by 300
- `w-100`, decrease width by 300
- `x300`, set X to 300
- `y+200`, increase Y by 200, (move lower)